# NHibernate Version Issue

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

I'm having a go at getting a test project up and running.  I've nabbed a load of code from this article.....

[Fluent NHibernate Automap with NHibernate Facility in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.crankingoutcode.com/post/Fluent-NHibernate-Automap-with-NHibernate-Facility-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

Problem is that I'm getting the following error....

> Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.1001,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match    the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've downloaded all the latest and greatest from NHibernate, Castle Project, and FluentNHibernate.  I've looked at the version of the NHibernate.dll that I am referencing in the project and it's 3.0.0.400.  Where and why is the solution complaining about 3.0.0.1001??????

For future use, I'd like to know how I find out what the problem is as well as the solution if possible.

Many thanks,

ETFairfax

**MORE INFO.......**

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

**Source Error:**

```
Line 45:             if (container == null)
Line 46:             {
Line 47:                 container = new WindsorContainer()
Line 48:                    .Install(
Line 49:                        Configuration.FromAppConfig(),

Source File: C:\Users\Public\Documents\TestCompany\Source\TestCompany.TestModule\MvcApplication2\Global.asax.cs    Line: 47 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = ETFairfax-TestCompany\ETFairfax
LOG: DisplayName = NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/TestCompany/Source/TestCompany.TestModule/MvcApplication2/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Public\Documents\TestCompany\Source\TestCompany.TestModule\MvcApplication2\bin
Calling assembly : ClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Public\Documents\TestCompany\Source\TestCompany.TestModule\MvcApplication2\web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/ETFairfax/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/25bf06cc/f1f41498/NHibernate.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/ETFairfax/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/25bf06cc/f1f41498/NHibernate/NHibernate.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/TestCompany/Source/TestCompany.TestModule/MvcApplication2/bin/NHibernate.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +64
   System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +58
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +50
   Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility.RegisterDefaultConfigurationBuilder() +133
   Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility.RegisterComponents() +29
   Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility.Init() +196
   Castle.MicroKernel.Facilities.AbstractFacility.Init(IKernel kernel, IConfiguration facilityConfig) +61
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(String key, IFacility facility) +182
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.AddFacility(String key, IFacility facility) +49
   Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUpFacilities(IConfiguration[] configurations, IWindsorContainer container) +242
   Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUp(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) +89
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers) +268
   MvcApplication2.MvcApplication.InitializeWindsor() in C:\Users\Public\Documents\TestCompany\Source\TestCompany.TestModule\MvcApplication2\Global.asax.cs:47
   MvcApplication2.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Users\Public\Documents\TestCompany\Source\TestCompany.TestModule\MvcApplication2\Global.asax.cs:62

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluent was probably built with a later version than the NHibernate asselbly you downloaded.

Theres a bundle of Fluent/NH3.0 at Fluent NHibernate website.

http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads